# Command line to install/upgrade .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Are there command line commands to install or upgrade .NET Core?

I checked to see if I had .NET Core was installed on my computer using `dotnet --version` only to notice that I still had the preview version installed on my computer. I was wondering if I could issue some commands to upgrade it to the latest version.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

There is no `dotnet` command to update .Net Core. Instead, you should use [the same approach you used to install it in the first place](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download), which depends on your OS.

Comment: A command line tool that can't update itself via the command line? Now I've seen everything!

Comment: what is the command for upgrading framework from net20 to net47

Comment: @VictorUde can't stop laughing after reading your comment :)

Comment: There is a plan to finally add this feature https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/23700

Comment: In @Serj link above, it is mentioned that you can update on Ubuntu and Windows: `apt-get upgrade dotnet-sdk-6.0`, and `winget install Microsoft.dotnet`

Answer (score 33):

Not promoted officially but it looks like there are approved packages on Chocolatey for .NET Core SDK.

https://chocolatey.org/packages/dotnetcore-sdk

Example:

```
> choco install dotnetcore-sdk
```

Or:

```
> choco upgrade dotnetcore-sdk
```

---

**Update (December 2020):** For .NET 5 the chocolatey package has changed since it's not technically branded as .NET Core any longer.

https://chocolatey.org/packages/dotnet-sdk/

Example:

```
> choco install dotnet-sdk
```

Or:

```
> choco upgrade dotnet-sdk
```

Answer (score 28):

If you have [WinGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/), then you can use it to install (or update) .NET:

```sh
winget install Microsoft.DotNet.SDK.Preview    # currently .NET 8.0 Preview
winget install Microsoft.DotNet.SDK.7
winget install Microsoft.DotNet.SDK.6
```

Run from an admin prompt

Answer (score 15):

For those who find this on search, there are [dotnet-install scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script) you can use. For example:

```
# Windows PowerShell
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1 -OutFile "$env:temp/dotnet-install.ps1"; powershell -executionpolicy bypass "$env:temp/dotnet-install.ps1"

# PowerShell Core
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1 -OutFile "$env:temp/dotnet-install.ps1"; pwsh "$env:temp/dotnet-install.ps1"

# Shell
wget https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh && chmod +x ./dotnet-install.sh && sudo ./dotnet-install.sh
```

* Note the [default install location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script#options) for these is different than the official installers; as said in another answer the easiest path to update is to use the same method you first installed with.

Edit: `apt` packages for Ubuntu 22.04+ [now includes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-6-is-now-in-ubuntu-2204/) `dotnet6` for the SDK. Other dotnet [packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=dotnet&searchon=names), such as just the runtime (`dotnet-runtime-6.0`, `aspnet-runtime-6.0`) can be installed as well.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dotnet6
```

Answer (score -3):

Just a heads up so you (or other people) don't struggle for hours as I did.

.NET Core 1.1.0 ships with SDK 1.0.0 Preview 2 (when this is written), but you need SDK 1.0.0 Preview 3.

Download and install .NET Core 1.1.0 as @svick suggested, then download and install SDK Preview 3 from: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/preview3-download.md